# How can I get the int type `_id` of mongodb in golang?

Tags: mongodb, go

First this is mongodb's data.

```
{
    _id : 1,
    "Test1" : "Hello",
    "Test2" : "MongoDB!",
}
```

And this is golang struct.

```
type P_SET struct {
    _id int
    Test1 string
    Test2 string
}
```

Next this is my golang code.

```
var pol P_SET
collection := client.Database("DBName").Collection("CollectionName")
err := collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{"_id": 1}).Decode(&pol)
```

But the result does not come with only `_id` data.

```
&{0, "Hello", "MongoDB!"}
```

I wonder why I can't get only `_id` values.

Comment: You need to export the _id field, i.e. change it to `ID` or `Id`, and use tags to indicate it should scan the `_id` from mongo.

Comment: ... the rules on decoding are listed here: https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#hdr-Structs

Comment: @mkopriva Oh! This works fine this way. i changed this source code `_id int` => `ID int "_id"`. Thanks!!

Comment: Note that the correct format for tags is `\`bson:"_id"\``, however since you say it works it's possible that the bson decoder already expects the `ID` field so you probably can remove the tag altogether. Here's some example of tags: https://golangcode.com/struct-tags/